# Restangular PUT method inserts ID even if I do not want it

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, restangular

I use the code below to get the schedule from a person and it works perfectly, but when I try to do a PUT it inserts an ID in front of the URL. I never set an ID for the second 'one' method, even setting it to 'null' the Restangular insists in adding and ID there.

Get code: Restangular.one('person', id).one('schedules').get()
URL when doing the GET: http://localhost:8090/person/1/schedules
URL when doing the PUT: http://localhost:8090/person/1/schedules/1

I believe it should be doing the PUT on the same URL Restangular did when getting, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you do get you are actually getting ALL the schedules for aircraft/1. to get a single schedule the url should be aircraft/1/schedule/ID

Same for PUT. When you do PUT you need to specify which schedule (ID) you want to update

Comment: My API expects the GET and PUT on the same URL, where 1 is the person ID. I can do it using the customPUT, but I would like to do it the normal way using regular PUT.